# SQL simple Query where company_name != to 'value'

Tags: sql

```
select employee_name
from works
where works.COMPANY_NAME != ('BP')
```

Below is the only table I need to reference

```
create table works (
employee_name varchar(100),
company_name varchar(100),
salary integer,
foreign key (employee_name) references employee(employee_name),
foreign key (company_name) references company(company_name),
check (salary > 0)
)
```

Why would this above query still return results of employee's who work for BP?  What am I doing wrong?  The query does run successfully but returns names of people who work for BP in my sample database.

Comment: I'm not sure about the parentheses. Try `WHERE company_name <> 'BP'`. Also, foreign keys on fields like *name* a terrible. Doesn't `company` have a better primary key?

Comment: What database you're on? On Oracle, you don't need parantheses. Just `!= 'BP'`

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS, `('BP')` and `'BP'` might not be the same. I am quite sure, you don't want the brackets.

Comment: @Phil yes, this has fixed my problem.  Please post as answer and I will accept.  I didn't realize <> is used for strings.  Can you also answer that in your answer?

Comment: @camdixon Not worth it really. I'm voting to close as a *typo* problem. The issue was **not** `!=` vs `<>`, it was most likely the paranetheses

Comment: @Phil What if I wanted to exclude multiple companies?  Would I then need the parenthesis?

Comment: @camdixon `NOT IN ('BP', 'Caltex', 'Mobil', 'etc')`

Answer (score 0):

you have used **varchar(100)**  that's might returns a set of spaces after it so you can have a
or you can have a `<>` sytax that will do you task

```
select employee_name
from works
where rtrim(works.COMPANY_NAME) <> 'BP'
```

Comment: What if the spaces are *before* the name?